# How to fill a column under certain conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames df (with 15000 rows) and df1 ( with 20000 rows)

Where df looks like

```
 Number   Color    Code     Quantity
  1        Red     12380     2
  2        Bleu    14440     3
  3        Red     15601     1
```

and df1 that has two columns `Code` and `Quantity` where I want to fill Quantity column under certain conditions using python in order to obtain like this

```
Code   Quantity
12380    2
15601    1
15640    1
14400    0
```

The conditions that I want to take in considerations are:

- If the two last caracters of Code column of df1 are both equal to zero, in this case I want to have 0 in the Quantity column of df1
- If I don't find the Code in df, in this cas I put 1 in the Quantity column of df1
- Otherwise I take the quantity value of df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try:

```
mask = df1['Code'].astype(str).str[-2:].eq('00')
mapped = df1['Code'].map(df.set_index('Code')['Quantity'])
df1['Quantity'] = mapped.mask(mask, 0).fillna(1)
```

**Details:**

Create a boolean `mask` specifying the condition where the last two characters of `Code` are both `0`:

```
>>> mask

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: Code, dtype: bool
```

Using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) map the values in `Code` column in `df1` to the `Quantity` column in `df` based on the matching `Code`:

```
>>> mapped

0    2.0
1    1.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
Name: Code, dtype: float64
```

[`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the values in the above `mapped` column where the boolean `mask` is `True`, and lastly fill the `NaN` values with `1`:

```
>>> df1

    Code  Quantity
0  12380       2.0
1  15601       1.0
2  15640       1.0
3  14400       0.0
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! However, I didn't understand why you used the map function to look in the other dataframe, because all I know about map function is that it is used only for substitution

Comment: `map` function can also be used to map the values in one series from the another series so in this example we are using `map` on the `Code` column in `df1` to map the corresponding values  to `Quantity` in `df` based on the matching `Code`. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes I see, but I dunno why I thought that it would be easier to user merge function

Comment: ofcourse you can also use `merge` but i guess its just more lines of code to manage.